Probability to end up in the last square of a board game and don't loop around anymore?
Let assume a square board, with 10 spaces per side (so 40 total). A player starts at 1st square, and on each turn rolls two six-sided dice, advancing forward a number of spaces equal to the sum of the two numbers that land face-up. If a player rolls a sum that would normally cause them to advance past the 40th square, they will instead "loop around" the board.
Let p be the probability that a player, after they "loop around" the board 5 times, lands on the space "Boardwalk" (the 40th square) before they "loop around" the board an eleventh time. Which integer is CLOSEST to the value of 12p?
I'm struggling with this question. Basically I compute the probability of ending in the 1st square and then do $(1-p)⁵$ so we have the probability of looping at least five times, but is the probability of looping to a second round while starting at first square the same than looping after the second round, knowing that we do not start the second loop at the first square? How to deal with that?

An approximation is to look at the average number of steps per move

Do you mean taking the average steps and then compute the probability once we are close (ie in the final spaces) of the board?

No - I mean take the average number of steps per move and take the reciprocal of that as a close approximation to the probability of landing on a particular space on a given circuit.
